# Retrieving SVN log files with SharpSVNs client.diff(uri, range, ouput) in no way edits the repository right?

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I have been using SharpSVN and love it but I wanted to make sure that the .GetLogs() and .Diff() functions in no way actually edit data on the repositories. These things just get you the information stored in the logs as if you were repo-browsing and looking at the logs through something like TurtoiseSVN right? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your assumption is correct. However, to test this you could access your repository using read-only credentials (how you set this up depends on your server type), and if everything succeeds then you aren't trying to modify your repository.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks, I've been using it on little things and it has been working great. I have not seen any changes in the repository itself. Today I started testing on a much larger/important repository, I didn't notice any but I wanted to double check and make sure. Come to think of it maybe I was only given read only privileges and I'm worrying for nothing, I'm just always really cautious around important things :) Thanks again for the suggestion I will make a note to do that.